# Concurrent kernel execution not working in AMD A10 APU

Tags: opencl, amd-processor

I have an AMD A10 APU with Radeon R7 GPU. I believe this device supportes concurrent kernel execution. But when i wrote the following code and obtained profiling information it doesnt seem like the kernels are executing concurrently. My openCL code is given below (The kernels within each iteration is added to the same queue and kernels in different iteration are added to different queues and hence should be running in parallel).

```
for(j = 0; j < 8; j++){
     cl_err = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue[4 + j],kernel[Q6_PROGRAM_ID][FILTER1_KERNEL],1,NULL,&globalSize,&localSize,4,eventList,&eventList[4 + j * 4]); //Invoking the first filter kernel
  cl_err = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue[4 + j],kernel[Q6_PROGRAM_ID][FILTER2_KERNEL],1,NULL,&globalSize,&localSize,1,eventList + 4 + 4 * j,&eventList[5 + j * 4]); //Invoking the second filter kernel
  cl_err = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue[4 + j],kernel[Q6_PROGRAM_ID][FILTER3_KERNEL],1,NULL,&globalSize,&localSize,1,eventList + 5 + 4 * j,&eventList[6 + j * 4]); //Invoking the third filter kernel
  cl_err = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue[4 + j],kernel[Q6_PROGRAM_ID][AGGREGATE_KERNEL],1,NULL,&globalSize,&localSize,1,eventList + 6 + 4 * j,&eventList[7 + j * 4]); //Invoking the aggregate kernel
}
```

The code i used for profiling is :

```
for(j = 0; j < 8; j++){
  //Code for obtaining the profiling data
  clWaitForEvents(4 + 4*j, eventList+4);
  clGetEventProfilingInfo(eventList[4 + j * 4], CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_QUEUED, sizeof(time_start_queued), &time_start_queued, NULL);
  clGetEventProfilingInfo(eventList[4 + j * 4], CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_START, sizeof(time_start), &time_start, NULL);
  clGetEventProfilingInfo(eventList[4 + j * 4], CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_END, sizeof(time_end), &time_end, NULL);
  total_time = ((double)time_end - time_start)/1000000;
  total_time_queued = ((double)time_end - time_start_queued)/1000000;
  final_time += total_time;
  final_time_queued += total_time_queued;


  cout<<"\n1 : "<<time_start<<" "<<time_end;


  clGetEventProfilingInfo(eventList[5 + j * 4], CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_QUEUED, sizeof(time_start_queued), &time_start_queued, NULL);
  clGetEventProfilingInfo(eventList[5 + j * 4], CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_START, sizeof(time_start), &time_start, NULL);
  clGetEventProfilingInfo(eventList[5 + j * 4], CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_END, sizeof(time_end), &time_end, NULL);
  total_time = ((double)time_end - time_start)/1000000;
  total_time_queued = ((double)time_end - time_start_queued)/1000000;
  final_time += total_time;
  final_time_queued += total_time_queued;


  cout<<"\n2 : "<<time_start<<" "<<time_end;


  clGetEventProfilingInfo(eventList[6 + j * 4], CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_QUEUED, sizeof(time_start_queued), &time_start_queued, NULL);
  clGetEventProfilingInfo(eventList[6 + j * 4], CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_START, sizeof(time_start), &time_start, NULL);
  clGetEventProfilingInfo(eventList[6 + j * 4], CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_END, sizeof(time_end), &time_end, NULL);
  total_time = ((double)time_end - time_start)/1000000;
  total_time_queued = ((double)time_end - time_start_queued)/1000000;
  final_time += total_time;
  final_time_queued += total_time_queued;


  cout<<"\n3 : "<<time_start<<" "<<time_end;


  clGetEventProfilingInfo(eventList[7 + j * 4], CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_QUEUED, sizeof(time_start_queued), &time_start_queued, NULL);
  clGetEventProfilingInfo(eventList[7 + j * 4], CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_START, sizeof(time_start), &time_start, NULL);
  clGetEventProfilingInfo(eventList[7 + j * 4], CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_END, sizeof(time_end), &time_end, NULL);
  total_time = ((double)time_end - time_start)/1000000;
  total_time_queued = ((double)time_end - time_start_queued)/1000000;
  final_time += total_time;
  final_time_queued += total_time_queued;


  cout<<"\n4 : "<<time_start<<" "<<time_end;
  }
```

The output of my profiling code is :

1 : 3989633359630 3989657015190

2 : 3989657016860 3989683273450

3 : 3989683275090 3989708840030

4 : 3989708841760 3989734915610

1 : 3989800219990 3989824648510

2 : 3989824650240 3989850888860

3 : 3989850890610 3989876392210

4 : 3989876393890 3989902432920

1 : 3989954275546 3989978865766

2 : 3989978867476 3990005037296

3 : 3990005038976 3990030592876

4 : 3990030594566 3990056566896

1 : 3990113144067 3990137315217

2 : 3990137316937 3990163458337

3 : 3990163460057 3990189007267

4 : 3990189008967 3990215129227

1 : 3990274589700 3990299102730

2 : 3990299104430 3990325570980

3 : 3990325572730 3990351050810

4 : 3990351052550 3990377255070

1 : 3990424871514 3990448828874

2 : 3990448830524 3990475309034

3 : 3990475310744 3990500849914

4 : 3990500851664 3990526839444

1 : 3990584574567 3990608802017

2 : 3990608803727 3990635102497

3 : 3990635104427 3990660647987

4 : 3990660649697 3990686716887

1 : 3990733269328 3990757174868

2 : 3990757176588 3990783429448

3 : 3990783431118 3990809003598

4 : 3990809005298 3990835207128

Comment: How do you construct the event list? Do kernels depend on other kernels?

Comment: kernels within an iteration depend on each other. Across iterations they are not dependent.i even replaced the eventList dependence with a (0,NULL) to see if the code works in that case. even then the kernels were being executed sequentially

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out why the kernels are not executing concurrently. For concurrent execution the GPU should have enough free resources available to support concurrent execution. In my code the number of work groups of each kernel was quite high and so the GPU only had enough resources to support 1 concurrent kernel. So keep the number of workgroups to a minimum to allow concurrent execution

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an out-of-order command queue (if supported by your driver) or multiple in-order command queues in order to get concurrent kernel execution.

Comment: each iteration of my loop is adding kernels to a different command queue (command queue 4 + j). Within an iteration the kernels are added to the same command queue as they are dependent and across iterations there are added to different command queues