# OpenCL: Single kernel working on independent arrays in parallel

Tags: c++, arrays, opencl

So I have a bunch of Arrays **A_i** of size **M x N_i** which are entirely independent and don't need to communicate with each other.

I've designed a kernel that I want to operate on each array separately, however since multiple kernels can't run at the same time, I would like to design a single kernel to operate on either all these arrays at once, or on batches of these arrays at a time.

Since these arrays all have the same number of rows, I could column-stack them into a single mega-array, and then use a single kernel with the appropriate off-sets to operate on each portion of this mega-array separately, however I'm looking for a cleaner solution.  Especially since the number of work-groups and work-items used for each **A_i** depends on its column-dimension **N_i**.

Hopefully this explanation is clear.

Comment: "since multiple kernels can't run at the same time" - This isn't generally true as far as I'm aware? You can kick off kernels asynchronously. The chances of being scheduled together are even better if the kernel is the same, just the data is different. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11763963/how-do-i-know-if-the-kernels-are-executing-concurrently

Comment: what sort of values / range do you use for i?